# How to limit or delete a log file on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I've already created a .log file in my iPhone app. But I need to limit the size of the file, erase its contents and start again to log the app activity.

I follow the steps in this webpage: http://blog.coriolis.ch/2009/01/09/redirect-nslog-to-a-file-on-the-iphone/#more-85

Any help will be appreciated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on the implementation of how you write to the log. If you directly redirect `STDERR` so that `NSLog()` statements would be output to a file, the most common approach is to use `freopen()`. In which case there isn't a way to check the size of the file while you're reading- the function appears to work atomically.